# Pandas get total of values

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 .... Col20
0   6    3    9    2           1
1   3    5    1    4          12
2   2    1    6    3           4
3   7    4    1    2           9  
....
```

I need to know, how many times each number appear. For example

```
Number  Total
1         4
2         3
3         3
4         3
5         1
6         1
...
12        1
```

Comment: `df.stack().value_counts()`